# Where's the best place to put custom devise actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've got a `User` resource generated by devise. The users have a `has_many` association with a model called `Parking`.

I need to create an action for listing all the parkings that belongs to a certain User. Without devise, I'd create a parkings action on `users_controller`, but I'm not sure how's the correct way of doing it devise-way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `controller` `parkings_controller`.Then In index method you can write your code to list all parkings that belongs to certain User.
like this ......

In your index method in `parkings_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @parkings = current_user.parkings
end
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I need to list all the parkings as well. I think it'd be a good idea to create a users_controller. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, to list all parkings that belongs to a specific User, you can use `users_controller` and to list all the parkings you can use `parkings_controller`.